# R - load files with condition

Tags: r

I have this simple script for loading files from my computer

```
files <- "C:/MyDrive/"   
setwd(files )
file_list <- list.files(path=files)
```

In my drive I have several files

```
sales_usa.xlsx
clients_usa.xlsx
sales_europe.xlsx
contracts_usa.xlsx
hq_europe.xlsx
usaReport.xlsx
unfinishedusa.xlsx
```

How to load ONLY files that contains usa in filename? (sales_usa.xlsx, clients_usa.xlsx, contracts_usa.xlsx, usaReport.xlsx, unfinishedusa.xlsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pattern` in `list.files`.  Here the pattern based on the files showed, 'usa.xlsx', thus we use the regex to `.*`  - characters till `usa` followed by a dot (`.` - metacharacter to match any character - so escape `\\`) and the 'xlsx' at the end (`$`) of the string

```
list.files(pattern = ".*usa\\.xlsx$")
```